# Find event device for keyboard, mouse

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, device-driver, linux-device-driver

What is a **foolproof** method to find the **event device node** for the hardware **keyboard** or **mouse**?

What I have tried is to read */proc/bus/input/devices* and search for *'Keyboard'* or *'Mouse'* in the device name, but this doesn't work always, as the device names vary a lot.

The other option was to select the ones with *Handlers=kbd* and *Handlers=mouseX*, but on a laptop, there are other devices like 'Power button', 'Video bus' with *Handlers=kbd* too.

Answer (score 0):

All input devices have `&input_class` value in the `dev->class` field. So you can iterate over all the devices and check for `(dev->class == &input_class)`. Next, for each input device you have found you'll need to see if it has a valid keyboard/mouse device name (for ex. "mice", "mouse%d", etc).

Comment: The device names vary a lot, and don't necessarily contain the words mouse, mice or keyboard!

Answer (score 0):

This is example to find keyboard event:

```
const std::string get_dev_event_kbd()
{
    std::string sline, sdev="/dev/input/", sH="", sBEV="";
    std::ifstream ifs("/proc/bus/input/devices");
    auto trimstr=[](std::string &s)
    {
        int i=0, n=s.length(); //left
        while ((i<n)&&((s[i]==' ')||(s[i]=='\t'))) i++;
        s=(i>0)?s.substr(i):s;
        n=s.length()-1; i=n; //right
        while ((i>0)&&((s[i]==' ')||(s[i]=='\t')||(s[i]=='\n')||(s[i]=='\r'))) i--;
        s=(i<n)?s.substr(0,i+1):s;
    };

    while (std::getline(ifs,sline).good())
    {
        if (sline[0]=='H')
        {
            sH=sline.substr(sline.rfind(" event"));
            trimstr(sH);
        }
        if (sline.substr(0,5)=="B: EV")
        {
            sBEV=sline.substr(sline.find('=')+1);
            trimstr(sBEV);
        }
        if (sBEV=="120013") break;
    }
    sdev+=sH;
    return sdev;
}
```

See: [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74903/explain-ev-in-proc-bus-input-devices-data) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94322/is-it-possible-for-a-daemon-i-e-background-process-to-look-for-key-presses-fr/94329#94329) for more details.
Also, if you get error 13 (Permission denied) error when doing open() on the device, check if group 'input' is defined for it and add your user to the group